# How to make Notification Center Widgets (iOS 5)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, widget, jailbreak

iOS 5 introduced Notification Center Widgets and I would like to experiment with those widgets and make custom ones (with a Jailbroken device). I couldn't quite figure out how to make such a widget. The Widgets (WeeApps) are bundles stored in /System/Library/WeeAppPlugins. It would be great if anyone has already writren a guide or could share how the principal class of a WeeApp has to look like. Ideal would be to have a WeeApp NIC template for theos :)

**Note:** This question is regarding so called WeeApps, system plugins for Notification Center introduced in iOS 5. Not to be confused with Today View Extensions introduced in iOS 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK i think i have found a good way to understand it, a sample widget with full source code available on github: https://github.com/WillFour20/WeeAppTest But whats most helpful is this tutorial and the NIC template for theos mentioned in the tutorial, I already made several widgets using this method and my custom NIC templates. http://weeplugins.com/blog/?p=1

Comment: This is only workable in combination with a jailbreak - right?

Answer (score 10):

I don't want to shameless-plug in here, but I wrote a small tutorial to help you with this.

[How to write Notification Center Widgets for iOS (iOS 6 and Below)](http://www.andyibanez.com/2012/02/20/how-to-create-a-notification-center-widget-for-ios/)

Hope it helps you!

**UPDATE**

Please note this is for iOS widgets running iOS 6 and below - In other words, this is for old jailbreak development. I may write an iOS 8 tutorial eventually, but this one is not it.