# How to make a Mobile Substrate tweak (Slide from top) Notification Center

Tags: jailbreak, tweak

I'm a whited00r developer and i'm creating an tweak for iPhone 2g/3g WHITED00r users a notification system (NS) ive already made one (NSCENTER) but it isnt really an tweak...

I want to make a mobile substrate tweak that if you slide from top it would show the tweak (activator) but I dont know how to do this. Could somebody help? or sample? or text help?

Comment: Look at the follow link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224895/how-to-make-notification-center-widgets-ios-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, you're basically looking to replace the Notification Center swipe gesture action to present your tweak, correct? If that's the case, `SBBulletinListController` has the methods you're looking for:

```
-(void)handleShowNotificationsGestureBeganWithTouchLocation:(CGPoint)touchLocation;
-(void)handleShowNotificationsGestureChangedWithTouchLocation:(CGPoint)touchLocation velocity:(CGPoint)velocity;
-(void)handleShowNotificationsGestureEndedWithVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity completion:(id)completion;
-(void)handleShowNotificationsGestureCanceled;
```

There are also corresponding methods in `Springboard` that you could try:

```
-(void)handleShowNotificationsSystemGesture:(id)gesture;
-(void)handleHideNotificationsSystemGesture:(id)gesture;
-(void)_showNotificationsGestureBeganWithLocation:(CGPoint)location;
-(void)_showNotificationsGestureChangedWithLocation:(CGPoint)location velocity:(CGPoint)velocity;
-(void)_showNotificationsGestureEndedWithLocation:(CGPoint)location velocity:(CGPoint)velocity;
-(void)_showNotificationsGestureFailed;
-(void)_showNotificationsGestureCancelled;
-(void)_hideNotificationsGestureBegan:(float)began;
-(void)_hideNotificationsGestureChanged:(float)changed;
-(void)_hideNotificationsGestureEndedWithCompletionType:(int)completionType velocity:(CGPoint)velocity;
-(void)_hideNotificationsGestureCancelled;
```

Try hooking those using MobileSubstrate. I haven't tried this myself, but it should point you in the right direction.